# UITableView doesn't display Address Book

Tags: ios, tableview, addressbook

I think I'm not getting the handle on address book and UITableView, or maybe I'm just making it simpler than it is.

here is my .h file:

```
@interface Contacts : UITableViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> {

NSMutableArray *menuArray;
NSString *firstName;
NSString *lastName;
UIButton *addcontact;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *menuArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *addcontact;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;

-(void)showPeoplePickerController;
@end
```

And my .m file:

```
 -(IBAction)addcontact:(id)sender {

ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker=[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

[peoplePicker setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];



[self presentModalViewController:peoplePicker animated:YES];  }
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
menuArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[super viewDidLoad];

} 

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:

(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker

  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    [menuArray addObject:firstName]; 
    lastName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    [menuArray addObject:lastName];



[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO;}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [menuArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSString *cellValue = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;

}
```

I hope someone could help me with it, I'm fairley new to UITableViews and Addressbooks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance purposes (not to mention animation purposes), UITableView does not automatically update itself whenever the data source changes.

Try adding `[myTableView reloadData];` after you add the first and last name to the arrays (or in `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tipp, but the view still isnt displaying the contacts. I have the slight hinch that firstName stays Nil for some reason.

Comment: Hmmm, one way to test that is to put an NSLog(@"%@", menuArray); after the [menuArray addObject:lastName]; line and see what the console prints out.

Comment: Well infact it doesnt stay empty. Its filled with the name. So why on earth won't the tableView display it o.O